# SQL query on denormalized tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join, oracle12c

I have these two below mentioned denormalized tables with out any data constraints. Records_audit will not have duplicate audit_id based rows though table doesn't have any constraints.

I will need SQL query to extract all fields of records_audit with an addtional matching column refgroup_Name from second table using matching condition of AuditID from both tables, printedCount greater than 1 and R_status as 'Y'. I tried to do with left join but it is selecting all records.

Can you help to correct my query? I tried with this below query but its selecting all unwanted from second table:

```
SELECT a.*, d.refgroup_Name 
from Records_audit a  
left join Patients_audit d ON ( (a.AUDITID=d.AUDITID ) 
                            and (a.printedCount> 1) 
                            AND (a.R_status='Y')
  )  
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Records_audit:

| AuditID | record_id | created_d_t | patient_ID | branch_ID | R_status | printedCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Img77862 | 2020-02-01 08:40:12.614 | xq123 | aesop96 | Y | 2 |
| 2 | Img87962 | 2021-02-01 08:40:12.614 | xy123 | aesop96 | Y | 1 |

Patients_audit:

| AuditID | dept_name | visited_d_t | patient_ID | branch_ID | emp_No | refgroup_Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Imaging | 2020-02-01 11:41:12.614 | xq123 | aesop96 | 976581 | finnyTown |
| 1 | EMR | 2020-02-01 12:42:12.614 | xq123 | aesop96 | 976581 | finnyTown |
| 2 | Imaging | 2021-02-01 12:40:12.614 | xy123 | himpo77 | 976581 | georgeTown |
| 2 | FrontOffice | 2021-02-01 13:41:12.614 | xy123 | himpo77 | 976581 | georgeTown |
| 2 | EMR | 2021-02-01 14:42:12.614 | xy123 | himpo77 | 976581 | georgeTown |

Comment: If you join both tables on AuditID, You will get 2 rows. Do you need 2 rows in the result??

Comment: I want selected rows from table 'Records_audit' based on criteria  " (a.printedCount> 1) 
                          and (a.R_status='Y') "and its AuditID matching  'refgroup_Name'  from Patients_audit table.

Comment: "*Records_audit will not have duplicate audit_id based rows though table doesn't have any constraints*" Could you add constraints to ensure that?

Comment: Thanks for checking. I wish I could make changes to this structure to allow constraints.  It was specifically used for analystics purposes though reporting  based applications got business rules in place restricting duplicate records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `left join` will give you all records in the "left" table, that is the `from` table. Since you have no `where` clause to constrain the query you're going to get all records in `Records_audit`.

See [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins) for more about joins.

If your intent is to get all records in `Records_audit` which have an R_status of `Y` and a `printedCount > 1`, put those into a `where` clause.

```
select ra.*, pa.refgroup_name 
from records_audit ra  
left join patients_audit pa on ra.auditId = pa.auditId
where ra.printedCount > 1
  and ra.r_status = 'Y'
order by ra.created_d_t desc
```

This will match all records in `Records_audit` which match the `where` clause. The `left join` ensures they match even if they do not have a matching `Patients_audit` record.

Other notes:

- Your `order by 3` relies on the order in which columns were declared in `Records_audit`. If you mean to order by `records_audit.created_d_t` write `order by a.created_d_t`.
- If your query is making an assumption about the data, add a constraint to make sure it is true and remains true.